# npm run coverage fails with "require(...).internalModuleStat is not a function"

Tags: node.js, npm, nyc

When we run our tests with `npm run test`, they pass. When we run with `npm run coverage`, though, some fail with this error:

```
'internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:58\n' +
    "const internalModuleStat = function (f) { return require('fs').internalModuleStat(f); };\n" +
    '                                                               ^\n' +
    '\n' +
    'TypeError: require(...).internalModuleStat is not a function\n' +
    '    at internalModuleStat (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:58:64)\n' +
    '    at stat (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:137:18)\n' +
    '    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:16)\n' +
    '    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:27)\n' +
    '    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)\n' +
    '    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)\n' +
    '    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1296:12)\n' +
    '    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:449:5)\n' +
    '    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:73:3)\n' +
    '    at internal/bootstrap/pkg.js:7:1\n'
```

What can be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen for many reasons. Here is a common root cause of similar problems:

> ##### Something may be messing up with the values of the `NODE_OPTIONS` variable.

The problem can be something else, but I would check the value `NODE_OPTIONS` as a possible culprit.

To understand why here is a...

### Case study

Here, we use both [`nyc`](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) (the test coverage tool) and [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

`nyc` sets an environment variable called `NODE_OPTIONS`; `pkg`, also, checks the value of this variable. So when we run coverage, the variable is changed by `nyc`. The value `nyc` sets, though, does not make sense to `pkg`. `pkg` gets lost then.

### How we solve it

Our solution was to reset the variable before running the tests.

In our case, we use [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), so we had a line like this in our `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "coverage": "nyc --reporter=lcov --include='src/**/*.js' npm test",
  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require @babel/register --recursive --exit",
}
```

We just added `NODE_OPTIONS=''` before calling `mocha`:

```
"scripts": {
  "coverage": "nyc --reporter=lcov --include='src/**/*.js' npm test",
  "test": "NODE_OPTIONS='' ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require @babel/register --recursive --exit",
}
```

Now, `npm run coverage` runs `nyc`, which sets the variable as needed. `nyc` then calls `npm run test`, whose script cleans up the variable.

### Your mileage may vary

Maybe your problem is not the same as the one above, or `NODE_OPTIONS` is messed up somewhere else. I hope, though, this answer can help you to figure out what is going on then.

Comment: setting NODE_OPTIONS='' resolved the issue.