# Cannot deploy to Firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

Although I am able to build my React app successfully and run locally, when I try to deploy to Firebase Hosting I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:59
const internalModuleStat = function (f) { return require('fs').internalModuleStat(f); };
                                                               ^

TypeError: require(...).internalModuleStat is not a function
```

Any ideas?

As a hint, this started happening after I started using sql.js in my project which also gave me build errors due to react-scripts using webpack 5. I was able to fix those with a polyfill plugin or by just downgrading react-scripts but in either case firebase deploy fails with the above error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to set

```
NODE_OPTIONS='' firebase deploy
```

Based on: [npm run coverage fails with "require(...).internalModuleStat is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087088/npm-run-coverage-fails-with-require-internalmodulestat-is-not-a-function)

Totally random but it worked now.